# Convert svg linear-gradient to CSS linear-gradient (Adobe XD)

Tags: svg, css, adobe-xd

I was given an Adobe .xd file for a website, which needs to be created in WordPress. Part of the design are linear-gradients (as borders of images for example). My problem is, that I can't seem to find an option for "extracting" the corresponding css from these elements.

An example:

[image]

Now, I want the CSS that describes this bottom border, which is a linear-gradient with an angle. I can get the hexcodes for the colors, but not the angle, nor do I know if there are stops and where.

The options I see are:

1. Extract the CSS from Adobe XD somehow. Is this possible?
2. Convert the `linearGradient` tag from the exported SVG file to css. How can this be done?

The linear gradient tag from the SVG of the exported bottom border is the following:

```
<linearGradient id="linear-gradient" x1="1.089" y1="-3.5" x2="-0.775" y2="2.611" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox">
  <stop offset="0" stop-color="#ac2284"/>
  <stop offset="1" stop-color="#003bff"/>
</linearGradient>
```

Comment: Looks like you just need to get the degree of the slope in this string of attributes:

x1="1.089" y1="-3.5" x2="-0.775" y2="2.611"

----

Then you can put them into this format for css:

background: linear-gradient(0deg,red,yellow,green);

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I needed to convert `<linearGradient>` from many SVG files to CSS, and I made this: https://codepen.io/JosephusPaye/pen/vbaxBa?editors=0010.

Paste an SVG source and it'll extract all the `<linearGradient>`s and convert them to CSS.

How it works, in summary:

- Parse the input as an SVG document
- Find all `<linearGradient>`s
- Calculate the slope angle using the `x1`, `x2`, `y1` and `y2` attributes
- Find all `<stops>` in the `<linearGradient>` and extract the offset, color and opacity
- Use the extracted angle and stops to generate a CSS gradient

See the source for more details.

Comment: I also left a comment in CodePen also, but the code errors out if any of the x1/x2 y1/y2 values are missing on the linearGradient. Defaults can be seen here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/linearGradient

Comment: @nVitius Updated, thanks!

Comment: This is amazing! Don't you have it also the other way round? From CSS to SVG?

Comment: For the record, I found this https://github.com/vibbio/css-gradient-angle-to-svg-gradient-coordinates